# Is it possible to run pgp 6.5.8 freeware on Windows 7 64 bit machine?

Tags: windows-7, pgp

I am trying to get the PGP Command Line -Freeware Version 6.5.8 by Networks Associates working on a Wndows 7 64 bit machine. Does anyone know if it is possible?

I installed it in C:\pgp

when i run pgp, it keeps telling me that it can't find the pgp.cfg file.

My PGPPATH is defined and set to C:\pgp

I have also included this path in my Path variable

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong. The documentation states that:

"The first time you start PGP, the software checks to see if the environment
variable PGPPATH is defined. If PGPPATH is defined, the software puts the
pgp.cfg in the %PGPPATH% directory"

Edit:

This is most likely a Windows 7 professional folder rights issue, since the file pgp.cfg can't get written. I tried my best given the folder full rights, but im not 100% confident that i did it right. Anyone help me?

Comment: FYI, the latest version of PGP is still (and, as far as I know, always will be) free for non-commercial use. You just have to download the latest trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that both the new environment variable is properly set, and that the path environment variable has definitely updated (do a reboot).

Check permissions on the folder that contains the `pgp.cfg` file, and on the file itself.

Finally, consider using [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org) instead; it's open source and free, and can be used from most common email clients; for example, [Outlook](http://www.nullamatix.com/how-to-gnupg-gpg4win-for-ms-office-outlook-exchange-and-others/).

EDIT:

Note that GPG can be driven from the command-line, although the passphrase needs to be piped in.  One example of how to do this is [here](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2003-October/020380.html), and a decryption example (which works the same for encryption) is [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2246746_do-batch-decrypting-gnupg.html).

Comment: Hi, i looked at GnuPG, and i could not find any portion that was command-line driven, and used for File encryption. I need a comman-line binary for windows that can be driven via a batch file. It will not be used for email. File encryption only. Files will then be SFTP'd.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i did all of the above in yor first two lines of suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking for symmetric or public key encryption?

Comment: public key encryption

Comment: I should note that i tested this on my Win32 machine and set it up identical, and the PGP.cfg file was created without any trouble....hmmmmm

Comment: Geoff, what do i actually download from http://www.gnupg.org/. What i downloaded ended up being purce source code. Can you give me the link to whay i need to download just for pgp file encryption (no email)?

Comment: I haven't used GPG in many years, but the last time I tried it I remember having trouble getting it to generate PGP-compatible keys due to the nonstandard extensions added to GPG. Later a major security vulnerability was discovered--I think it turned out that if you used the default hashing algorithm to sign your data, someone could easily crack your private key. After that, I gave up on GPG and decided to go back to PGP.

Comment: @JohnnyHolmes - Have you looked at the [GPG4Win](http://gpg4win.org/) site? I believe that will give you binaries.

Comment: @rob - I assume you're talking about the SHA-1 problem mentioned [here](http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/ss/sec-key/sec-key.htm)? If so, it affected both PGP and GPG.  Note that SHA-1 itself [has been broken for a while](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html).  All that said - encryption software is definitely a personal choice, so it comes down to evaluating the choices, the current state of each, and takin' your chances :-)

Comment: @Geoff: The particular vulnerability I was referring to had to do with ElGamel keys, but point taken. To me it seemed at the time that  GPG was too focused on incorporating bleeding-edge features and optimizations which, as it turns out, has led directly to major vulnerabilities in the product on multiple occasions. Maybe GPG has matured enough in the past several years that it isn't a significant issue any more. If I were re-evaluating the two products again, I'd probably compile a side-by-side comparison of each product's vulnerabilities and bug fixes over the past several years.

Comment: Thanks, i have moved on to gpg. because PGP Command line freeware is old and no longer supported.  Howver, i am having trouble with a particular command using GPG. I will make a separate post. - thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Sad but true; the presently available PGP (GnuPG etc) won’t run on Windows 64-bit machines. Not the frontends, nor the key-handlers, nor the encryption-engines.

The problem with the commercial PGP—besides the price—is that the PGP development is nowadays driven by the companies that implement it. Anyone will understand that enterprises are not interested in endpoint encryption but in gateway encryption. The employee syncs via SSL or pre-shared, smartcard-certificates (which is for the communication sector) and the servers talk PGP. This way, no employee can hide information from their company and virus-protection can be implemented on the gateway.

I recommend using S/MIME with certificates. If s.o. doesn’t like to buy TTP-certificates (trusted 3rd party) from Comodo, Thawte, Global-Sign, Veri-sign, etc., he could join a WOT (Web-of-trust) like CA-cert. The only disadvantage is, that friends and commercial partners have to be informed in advance, that getting the CA-cert root-certificate is required (it is not pre-installed in Windows/Mozilla out-of-the-box).

Regarding convenience, that won’t make a practical difference. Using PGP requires all commercial partners to pre-trust the keys and to pre-consider which of their friends they trust. In my opinion, that is the equivalent to informing friends and commercial partners that they need the root-certificate and that they need to check fingerprints (same as PGP).

PGP enthusiasts should at least once in their lifetimes generate a key from someone in their "friend-trust", sign it and forward it to all others (even to the one who is the faked owner of that key). I predict, before the faked key is blacklisted, almost half of the PGP-friend-trust is already using that key.